# random genaration of image from drawable folder in android

Tags: android, image, random

Android version:4.2
I am developing an android App. I need to generate images from drawable folder randomly. In my drawable I have 45 images with different names.
My xml code is:

```
<ImageView
android:id="@+id/imageView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

I have tried with this code:

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Random rand = new Random();
int rndInt = rand.nextInt(52) + 1;
String drawableName = "photo"+ rndInt;

int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(drawableName, "drawable",  getPackageName());
img.setImageResource(resID);
```

But with this code I need to change my image names to `photo1`, `photo2`, ... and I don't want to do it.

Any suggestion on how to implement it? Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way is to create an array with required image's ids. And take random one from that array. That approach is explained in other answers.

Another way is to create file `random_images_array.xml` in `values` folder of your project and fill it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <array name="apptour">
        <item>@drawable/image_1</item>
        <item>@drawable/photo_2</item>
        <item>@drawable/picture_4</item>
    </array>

</resources>
```

And then you can take random image from that xml array:

```
final TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_images_array);
final Random rand = new Random();
final int rndInt = rand.nextInt(imgs.length());
final int resID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);
```

Third method is to take random field from R.drawable class:

```
final Class drawableClass = R.drawable.class;
final Field[] fields = drawableClass.getFields();

final Random rand = new Random();
int rndInt = rand.nextInt(fields.length);
try {
    int resID = fields[rndInt].getInt(drawableClass);
    img.setImageResource(resID);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanq vasart..third form worked me perfectly.Thank you so much.:)

Comment: hi vasart..is there any way to get which field is selectd randomly i mean image name???

Comment: Yep, you can do that: `fields[rndInt].getName()`

Comment: hi vasart..is there any way to put exception so that some images should not involve in that random selection????

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
long[] res = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};
```

or

```
int[] res = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2};
```

and

```
 int rndInt = rand.nextInt(res .length);



img.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(res[rndInt]));
```

Comment: Thanq ngesh.I followed ur code but It is showing me this error:The method setImageResource(int) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (long)

Answer (score 3):

Be specific about your question - what do you actually want to do?

if you want to show images in random order than this would be best

```
        int resId[]={R.drawable.p1,R.drawable.p2,R.drawable.p2};
         Random rand = new Random();
         int index = rand.nextInt((resId.length- 1) - 0 + 1) + 0;

         imgView.setImageResource(resId[index]);
```

If you want the absolute file path of image to rename it, see [this article](http://maulik-dhameliya.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-get-absolute-path-of-drawable.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageView img=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
String[] imageArray = {"Image1", "Image2", etc..};
Random rand = new Random();

int rndInt = rand.nextInt(52) + 1;
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(imageArray[rand], "drawable",  getPackageName());
img.setImageResource(resID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to see this question or answer also:-

[Randomize string from resources android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517585/randomize-string-from-resources-android/15517657#15517657)

but you have to replace

```
textview.setText()
```

to

```
img.setImageResource(ran.nextInt(trivias.length)]);`
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting an array with all of the drawables and then getting a random index through a random number would work.

```
public int[] Images = {R.drawable.1, R.drawable.2, R.drawable.3};
```

And then

```
ImageView EightBallImage = findViewById(R.id.EightBallImage);
EightBallImage.setImageResource(Images[new Random().nextInt(Images.length)]);
```

Either inside a click listener or just in the onCreate method