# Cycle random images in Android

Tags: java, android, xml, image, random

I'm beginner to Android / Java development. I just started learning programming and the easiest way for me is to modify open source projects to understand the principles involved.

Anyways, I want to do a very simple modification to Bubble Shoot game, 5-10 different background images will be cycled randomly:

- when every new level is started (but remain the same when the level is just restarted)
- or much easier: background is changing every single time when the level is restarting or starting

I defined a string array of background drawables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="random_background"></string-array>
        <item name="background_01">@drawable/background01</item>
        <item name="background_02">@drawable/background02</item>
        <item name="background_03">@drawable/background03</item>
        <item name="background_04">@drawable/background04</item>
        <item name="background_05">@drawable/background05</item>
        <item name="background_06">@drawable/background06</item>
        <item name="background_07">@drawable/background07</item>
        <item name="background_08">@drawable/background08</item>
        <item name="background_09">@drawable/background09</item>
        <item name="background_10">@drawable/background10</item>

</resources>
```

The original code define the background on *GameView.java* in **SRC** folder:

```
  mBackgroundOrig =
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.background, options);
```

Please help me to create an easy way for this idea.

Also I have few questions:

- The xml file must be in res/values correct ? Can I use any file name for it ? For example: *random.xml*
- I got this error with the xml file: **error: A 'type' attribute is required for item** Do I need to setup the type and format for each item ? If yes, what type and which format please ?
- Can we avoid exceeding the video memory limit ? I mean to load only the current background, and after each use to be flush out before a new random image will be displayed.

***Notes:*** Bubble Shoot source code: https://code.google.com/p/bubble-shoot/

Background pictures file names: background01.jpg, background02.jpg, etc.

Thank you very much,

Paul

Comment: have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545753/random-genaration-of-image-from-drawable-folder-in-android/15546032#15546032

Comment: This worked. It's randomly changing the background. Now I have another issue. It's changing only when I restart the app. I need the app to change the background when the game is changing the level (nextLevel). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the string array is indexed by numbers it's really easy to do what you're describing and use whatever images you like.

Assuming that you're careful to type out their names exactly as they are in the drawables folder.

So your array (which doesn't need named items) would look like

```
<string-array name="myImages">
    <item>foo</item>
    <item>bar</item>
    <item>image7</item>
    <item>king_kong</item>
</string-array>
```

and so forth.  Drawables would  need to contain images foo.jpg, bar.jpg, etc.

Now in your code you pull a random number that is between 0 and the length of this array and then you get your drawable like this:

```
int randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myImages).length);
Field field = R.drawable.class.getField(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myImages)[randomNum]);
int imgId = field.getInt(null);

myImg.setImgResource(imgId);
```

I'm writing this from memory, so it may have typos, but you get the general idea.

Comment: My working code:




      TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_background);
      Random rand = new Random();
      int rndInt = rand.nextInt(imgs.length());
      int resID = imgs.getResourceId(rndInt, 0);

       mBackgroundOrig =
       BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resID, options);'




But it's changing only when I restart the whole app. I want to change the background when the level is changing. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: You need to call this code when your level is changing, I suppose! :)

Comment: How can I do that ? Can you give me an example using the above code please ? I'm new to Android / Java. Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea how you're starting your levels.  At whatever point you are doing that, that's where you should introduce the code. If you post your game code, I could probably look at it and tell you, but I suspect you really can figure this out on your own.

Comment: I can't figure this out. The level manager code is here: https://code.google.com/p/bubble-shoot/source/browse/trunk/bubble-shooter-pro/src/com/likeapp/game/bubbleshooter/LevelManager.java?r=6 . I'm assuming goToNextLevel() need to call the rand background code. Please show me an example how exactly to make the call between those two codes. Thank you.

Comment: there's a `goToNextLevel()` method in your code and you have your Context ('mContext'). Just add my code sample into that method, and add mContext to getResources().  myImg is whatever the ImageView is that you're changing. Presumably you know its id and can get it via mContext.findViewById(R.id.someId)

Comment: I'd like to create a new file with a class and a method with your rand code. I want to have it as a separate method because I can call it from everywhere I want not only from goToNextLevel() right ? Can you show me a way to do that please ? It's the thing I'm struggling to learn: packages / classes / methods etc. Thanks.