# Make system randomly choose a toast to show on click

Tags: android, toast

I have a button that stops a recording and when it's clicked, it currently pops up a toast notification. I was thinking it would be a little cooler if I could have multiple toast messages and the system would randomly choose (and show) one of the toasts so the user doesn't receive the same message EVERY time they finish a recording. I don't know if this is actually possible, I was just curious.

Code of my onClick():

```
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            /*startButton.setEnabled(true);
            stopButton.setEnabled(false); */
            recorder.stop();
            recorder.release();
            addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
            startButton.setEnabled(true);
            stopButton.setEnabled(false);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Awesome Recording!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really show much effort. There are many ways to go about doing this. You need to learn how to generate pseudo-random numbers in a range (that matches the amount of strings you have to show) and cross reference it to your strings xml somehow to pull the appropiate text. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15517585/randomize-string-from-resources-android

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you very much. Sorry, I'll try to research more next time. Hats off to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit 2

My mistake, the `new Random().nextInt(...)` line returns the same integer multiple times because the random number generator in Java is actually pseudo-random; it uses a seed to generate the random values and creating a new `Random` object every time resets the seed, resulting in repeating integers. Try adding this field to your anonymous `OnClickListener`:

```
private static final Random random = new Random();
```

and change

```
new Random().nextInt(toastMessages.length - 1);
```

to

```
random.nextInt(toastMessages.length - 1);
```

so you end up with the following:

```
stopButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    private static final Random random = new Random();

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        recorder.stop();
        recorder.release();
        addRecordingToMediaLibrary();
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);

        String[] toastMessages = new String[] {"Great!", "Awesome!", "..."};
        int randomMsgIndex = random.nextInt(toastMessages.length - 1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastMessages[randomMsgIndex], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

---

This solution isn't specific to Android, but you could use an array of predefined messages (preferably, you should be loading these from `strings.xml`):

```
String[] toastMessages = new String[] {"Great!", "Awesome!", "..."};
```

and then choose an index from that array at random:

```
new Random().nextInt(toastMessages.length - 1);
```

to give you:

```
String[] toastMessages = new String[] {"Great!", "Awesome!", "..."};

// Get an index between 0 and the last index in the messages array 
int randomMsgIndex = new Random().nextInt(toastMessages.length - 1);

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toastMessages[randomMsgIndex], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

---

EDIT: Eclipse should handle this for you, but just to make sure:

```
import java.util.Random;
```

Comment: Okay, so I tried this and it does print out one of the strings in the array, but it only prints the first one. It never prints any of the others. How can I fix this?

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. Please check the updated solution.

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was going for and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

Sure this is possible. The simplest way I can think of, if there is a certain number of messages you want to display, is to simply create a `String Array` holding the different messages. Then in `onClick()` just use a random number generator to choose a message from the `Array`.

So like

```
Random randomNumber = new Random();
int number = randomNumber.nextInt(5); // where 5 is the number of Strings minus 1
Toast.makeText(YourActivityName.this, YourStringArray[number], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: This works really well, thanks codeMagic! But for some reason it only prints one of the strings. It never goes to another string?